# bootstrap tab skin remove unwanted space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create skin for bootstrap tab panel.
I have my basic markup ready and I created this:

[image]

however I have unwanted line in active tab and unwanted space between hover tab underline and line below.
I can fix this by setting height on `ul` to 34px, but can this be fixed without setting height?

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/b3qL5/32/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
.gittabs ul.nav li a {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 #ba5d0f;
}
```

Comment: A very nice solution indeed. I was gonna use a pseudo element but this is just wonderful.

Comment: I added `position: relative` and `top: 1px` to all ul.li elements, this way they all are same position :)